# rclone migration error from Amazon S3 to Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, object-storage

Following the oficial tutorial of Digital Ocean '[How To Migrate from Amazon S3 to DigitalOcean Spaces with rclone](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-amazon-s3-to-digitalocean-spaces-with-rclone)' I got to do all work well, less the more important: 'rclone sync s3:source-of-files spaces:dest-of-files' (Migrate); I faced an error like this:

> 2017/11/07 18:25:02 ERROR : uploads/figure_block/data/1658752/thumb_dor.jpg: Failed to copy: InvalidArgument:
>       status code: 400, request id: tx00000000000000651804a-005a01fa7e-3f966-nyc3a, host id:

What may be wrong?

Comment: For now, I don't know why! But, the tutorial just works with the version v1.32 of rclone; AND, running from unziped folder, without install; Any news, please post here!